# Changing of disk partition with netrw on Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, netrw

I guess this is not a problem for Linux users, but in Windows disks have drive letters. How can I switch drive letters in netrw on Window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23161254/4194289):

```
:e D:\
```

will open the D:\ drive in a netrw buffer.

Still according to the answer, you can use `:cd D:\` to change the current directory and then use your favorite netrw command.